# Django ModelAdmin and Dropdown Values

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

in app/models.py:

```
class Template(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User);
```

in app/admin.py:

```
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('user', 'status',);
```

When I edit Template table in Site Adminitration, I get a dropdown for user field. The value in the dropdown is 'username', but app_templates stores the user value as 'user_id'.

How do I make such that the dropdown in Site Adminitration will show combination of first_name, last_name, email instead of 'username'? But, 'templates' table will store the value as 'id'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django Docs:

> The **unicode** (**str** on Python 3) method of the model will be
>   called to generate string representations of the objects for use in
>   the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass
>   ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will
>   receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for
>   representing it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

So to override it:

```
class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '%s - %s - %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.email)

class TemplateAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TemplateAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'] = UserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TemplateAdminForm
```

Comment: How would I change this to show firstname + lastname and store the username instead of the id?

Answer (score 0):

Change 'user' to:

```
list_display = ('full_username')
```

Add the following to class Template:

```
def full_username(self):
    return str(self.user.first_name) + ' ' + str(self.user.last_name) + ' ' + str(self.user.email);
```